# Как запретить вставлять текст в input через правый клик мыши?

Tags: input, мышь

Собственно нужно скриптом запретить вставлять в input текст из буфера мышкой через правый клик, при этом оставить работоспособным ввод с клавиатуры и Ctrl+V

```html
<input type="text" class="fw text price-all" name="fld15" id="order-fld-15" value="" pattern="^\d+\.?(\d{1,2})?$" placeholder="Цена: 0.00 €" size="8">
```

Comment: Заблокировать правый клик на инпуте например?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с jquery можно так, например:

```
$("#order-fld-15").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`oncontextmenu = 'return false';`

```html
<input oncontextmenu='return false;' type="text" class="fw text price-all" name="fld15" id="order-fld-15" value="" pattern="^\d+\.?(\d{1,2})?$" placeholder="Цена: 0.00 €" size="8">
```